# What is the most efficient way to store and work with a floating point number with 1,000,000 significant digits in C?

Tags: c, math, floating-point

I'm writing a utility to calculate π to a million digits after the decimal.  On a 32- or 64-bit consumer desktop system, what is the most efficient way to store and work with such a large number accurate to the millionth digit?

clarification: The language would be C.

Comment: I must say, this stretches the notion of "utility".

Comment: yes, but i've been puzzling over this for awhile... googled it, looked it up in articles, and still am not sure exactly the best way to go about it.

Comment: Are you referring to decimal or binary digits?  Which arbitrary precision arithmetic packages have you looked at?  (GMP, PARI are two that spring to mind, along with the arithmetic in OpenSSL and the stuff that Dave Hanson did for his C Interfaces book; there are many others.)

Comment: decimal digits.  to name a few, there's apfloat, FMLIB, BMP, mpmath...

Comment: If you asked the question "how do I efficiently calculate successive digits of pi" then some of the answers wouldn't involve working with large numbers of digits.

Comment: hi pete, yes, but that's not the question.  there are many very well known techniques and equations to calculate successive digits of pi.  the problem isn't in caluculating the digits of pi.  it's in storing them all, and then using those digits to do something useful (which would require being able to retrieve the numbers and do math with them)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Forget floating point, you need bit strings that represent integers

This takes a bit less than 1/2 megabyte per number. "Efficient" can mean a number of things. Space-efficient? Time-efficient? Easy-to-program with?

Your question is tagged *floating-point*, but I'm quite sure you do not want floating point at all. The entire idea of floating point is that our data is only known to a few significant figures and even the famous constants of physics and chemistry are known precisely to only a handful or two of digits. So there it makes sense to keep a reasonable number of digits and then simply record the exponent.

But your task is quite different. You must account for every single bit. Given that, no floating point or decimal arithmetic package is going to work unless it's a template you can arbitrarily size, and then the exponent will be useless. So you may as well use integers.

What you really really need is a string of bits. This is simply an array of convenient types. I suggest `<stdint.h>` and simply using `uint32_t[125000]` (or 64) to get started. This actually might be a great use of the more obscure constants from that header that pick out bit sizes that are fast on a given platform.

To be more specific we would need to know more about your goals. Is this for practice in a specific language? For some investigation into number theory? If the latter, why not just use a language that already supports Bignum's, like Ruby?

Then the storage is someone else's problem. But, if what you really want to do is implement a big number package, then I might suggest using bcd (4-bit) strings or even ordinary ascii 8-bit strings with printable digits, simply because things will be easier to write and debug and maximum space and time efficiency may not matter so much.

Comment: great points.  this is an investigation into cs theory.  I'm using C as the language as it's what i'm most familiar with.  I'm using the PI algorithm as algorithms for it are well known as well as the exact digits up to tens of millions of digits, so I can test my algorithm out to see if it's working.  Efficiency would, as is always, a tradeoff between memory and time.  thanks!

Comment: Thank you for giving me a reason to actually *like* Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend storing it as an array of short ints, one per digit, and then carefully write utility classes to add and subtract portions of the number. You'll end up moving from this array of ints to floats and back, but you need a 'perfect' way of storing the number - so use its exact representation. This isn't the most efficient way in terms of space, but a million ints isn't very big.

**It's all in the way you use the representation. Decide how you're going to 'work with' this number, and write some good utility functions.**

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply.  with the algorithms already known and out there, I can quickly generate more digits than I know how to handle.  The problem would come with doing any sort of floating point math, I'm not sure how to tell whether the result is accurate or if it's being affected by the nuances of, say, an IEEE 754 float.  I could calculate it one digit at a time, and storing them all as a huge C array of shorts... but that seems to be brute force

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to tolerate computing pi in hex instead of decimal, there's a [very cute algorithm](http://www.experimentalmath.info/bbp-codes/bbp-alg.pdf) that allows you to compute a given hexadecimal digit without knowing the previous digits.  This means, by extension, that you don't need to store (or be able to do computation with) million digit numbers.

Of course, if you want to get the nth *decimal* digit, you will need to know all of the hex digits up to that precision in order to do the base conversion, so depending on your needs, this may not save you much (if anything) in the end.

Comment: using hex instead of decimal is a neat idea, and would allow you to store more digits, in a way, per digit.  and would take up less room, work nicely with binary math, etc... but having to calculate out each digit successively and not storing the result would be a killer.  neat algorithm.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're writing this purely for fun and/or learning, I'd recommend using a library such as [GNU Multiprecision](http://gmplib.org/).  Look into the `mpf_t` data type and its associated functions for storing arbitrary-precision floating-point numbers.

If you are just doing this for fun/learning, then represent numbers as an array of `chars`, which each array element storing one decimal digit.  You'll have to implement long addition, long multiplication, etc.

Comment: wouldn't that incur a lot of overhead converting a char to a digit and back for each element?

Comment: Not if you treat them as raw bytes instead of ASCII characters.  If you used `'0'` through `'9'`, you'd have a little extra overhead, but not if you just used `(char)0` through `(char)9`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP).

Answer (score 1):

You could store its decimals digits as text in a file and mmap it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

i once worked on an application that used really large numbers (but didnt need good precision). What we did was store the numbers as logarithms since you can store a pretty big number as a log10 within an int.

Think along this lines before resorting to bit stuffing or some complex bit representations.

I am not too good with complex math, but i reckon there are solutions which are elegant when storing numbers with millions of bits of precision.

Comment: numbers as logs, interesting thought.  but i guess that's where only requiring good precision would work.  log10 of a huge number, and converting back won't always equal the same number.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, any programmer of arbitrary precision arithmetics needs understanding of base conversion. This solves anyway two problems: being able to calculate pi in hex digits and converting the stuff to decimal representation and as well finding the optimal container.

The dominant constraint is the number of correct bits in the multiplication instruction.
In Javascript one has always 53-bits of accuracy, meaning that a Uint32Array with numbers having max 26 bits can be processed natively. (waste of 6 bits per word).

In 32-bit architecture with C/C++ one can easily get A*B mod 2^32, suggesting basic element of 16 bits. (Those can be parallelized in many SIMD architectures starting from MMX). Also each 16-bit result can contain 4-digit decimal numbers (wasting about 2.5 bits) per word.